# how to store incoming data line by line into a text file

Tags: c#, writetofile

[image]

there is an incoming data from COM and I am saving this data to a txt file. however the problem is that I can not save the incoming data line by line as it is shown on the black screen.

Can somebody help, how is that possible to save it exactly the same way into the text file. Here is the code I use

the serialport code handles the incoming data and saveittoFile part handles how to transfer it to a file.

```
  void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        object incomingData=null;
        string line= string.Empty;
        richTextBox1.Visible=true;

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            try
            {
                msg = ComPort.ReadExisting();
                richTextBox1.Text += msg;
                incomingData = msg;
                saveitTofile(incomingData);
            }
            catch
            {
                richTextBox2.Text = " timeout exception";
            }




     public void saveitTofile(object value)
     {
        string textFilePath =    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["textFilePath"];
        StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter(textFilePath, true);
        txt.WriteLine(value);
        txt.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the line endings? You probably just need to replace `\r` or `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: It looks like your code is already telling it to save it line by line. Is the problem that there are less characters per line in the console?

Comment: @aguertin if you look at the black screen( which the incoming data), it is not the same text as stated in txt file.

Comment: In that case, I would do what Manfred Radlwimmer recommended. Parse the incomingData for \n.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I have not used them in my code. there should be another way of transferring the data line by line exactly the same in the black screen.

Comment: @aguertin the problem is that after each call, it transfers the data as one line.

Comment: @chatay Most likely wherever that data is coming from is where they are being placed(the newline feed)

Comment: @chatay why is it a problem? Just parse the data before you invoke the save data function. Your variable "incomingData" can be parsed for newline characters.

Comment: try to open your text file with Notepad++, it process line ending more correctly

Comment: @AntonSemenov thanks, it works!.

Comment: @chatay this means that the string your recieved has only `\n` symbol at the end of line. You can replace it with `"\n\r"` as Manfred Radlwimmer said: `saveitTofile(incomingData.Replace("\n", "\n\r"));`

Comment: @AntonSemenov 'saveitTofile(incomingData.ToString().Replace("\n", "\n\r"));' it did not work

Comment: @chatay OK, then there is no '\n' symbol at the end:-) You can investigate which one you received from COM por and replace it with `"\n\r"` (common EOF sequence)

Comment: @AntonSemenov I debug the program, there is "\n\r" at the end of every line, but it does not display it in txt file, it is more clear in notepad++.

Comment: @chatay I've performed some tests and figure out that notepad interprets `\r\n` as new line but leave away `\n\r` unrecognized. So you need `\r\n` at the line end. I used this code to write simple test file `txt.Write("line1\n\rline2\r\nline3");`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    dosya.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
                }`    this is the answer for those who got stuck onto this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should process the data on the fly when it's red from communication port. Then pack full lines into `Queue<>` and fire some `event` that will be caught by your storing routine.

To make it as such you can make some kind of `Communication` object that will be only used to communicate with the communication port :

```
public class Communication
{
    // initialize every variable needed to communicate

    // and three more fields
    string _unfinishedLine = string.Empty;

    public Queue<string> LinesQueue = new Queue<string>();

    public event EventHandler LineAdded;

    public Communication()
    {
        ComPort.DataReceived += WhenDataReceived;
    }

    void WhenDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = ComPort.ReadExisting();
        string line = _unfinishedLine;
        int brcount = 0;
        while ( QueueMessage(ref line, out brcount, message) )
        {
            LinesQueue.Enqueue(line);
            message = message.Remove(0, line.Length + brcount);
            EventHandler handler = LineAdded;
            if(handler != null)
                handler(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        _unfinishedLine = line;
    }

    bool QueueMessage(ref string line, out int brcount, string message)
    {
        // line endings in ASCII :
        //  LF ( \n ) = 0x0A
        //  CR ( \r ) = 0x0D
        //  CR/LF ( \r\n ) = 0x0D0A
        const char CR = (char)0x0D;
        const char LF = (char)0x0A;
        // now check for the line endings
        int idx = message.IndexOf(CR);
        if(idx != -1)
        {
             if(idx + 1 < message.Length && message[idx + 1] == LF)
             {
                 // CR/LF line ending
                 line = message.Substring(0, idx);
                 brcount = 2;
             }
             else
             {
                 // CR line ending
                 line = message.Substring(0, idx);
                 brcount = 1;
             }
             return true;
        }
        else if ( (idx = message.IndexOf(LF)) != -1 )
        {
            // LF line ending
            line = message.Substring(0, idx);
            brcount = 1;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // no break line signs found.. store message and add signs to it
            line = message;
            brcount = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now since you have your `Communication` object that reads from the serial port you can update your view/write code part :

```
// instead of :
// void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
// you now should have :
void WhenLineAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while ( communicationObject.LinesQueue.Count > 0 )
    {
        string message = communicationObject.LinesQueue.Dequeue();
        richTextBox1.Text += message;
        string textFilePath =    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["textFilePath"];
        using (StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter(textFilePath, true))
        {
            txt.WriteLine(message);
            txt.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Validate this [online in here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BeC1qB)

Give me some feedback if it helped or not.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, great work, however I am unfamiliar with some of the basic codes you used, I am kinda newbie and have to figure out some of the terms you used such as Queue. Also  `else if ( (idx = message.IndexOf(LF) != -1 ))` it gives cannot implicity convert bool to int error

Comment: @chatay My bad this should be `else if ( (idx = message.IndexOf(LF)) != -1 )` you can now check the edited answer. The `Queqeq` is an object which acts as "FI-FO" type of list. Meaning FirstIn - FirstOut. You can read documentation on msdn platform for this one.